# What is 'Minimum corpus frequency for terms' in Wordnik API?

Tags: api, dictionary, wordnik

When requesting for words using Wordnik API, you can specify minimum and maximum corpus frequency.

http://developer.wordnik.com/docs#!/words/search_words

What exactly is corpus frequency in this case and how is it measured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corpus frequency is the measure of how many times a (case-sensitive) word has been found, and is based on the millions of documents consumed by Wordnik.  You can use this measure to determine the "commonality" of a word.